# ApacheDS startup, wrapper nod found

Tags: wrapper, startup, apacheds

I am hoping the group can help me. I have been using ApacheDS for development purposes for about 6 months and I am really happy with it. No problem running on Ubuntu linux on my laptop.

I recently started to create my production environment for the LDAP server. The production server is running in Atlantic.net Cloud environment on a dedicated server. I did the install of DS with no problems. But when I try to start DS I get the following error:

/opt/apacheds-2.0.0-M10/bin/apacheds: 1: eval: /opt/apacheds-2.0.0-M10/bin/wrapper: not found

the wrapper file is located where eval is looking, so I have no idea why "not found" is occurring.

If I call the wrapper directly, ./wrapper start default
I get:
-bash: ./wrapper: No such file or directory

Below is the bin directory
drwxr-xr-x 2 apacheds apacheds  4096 Feb 24 10:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 apacheds apacheds  4096 Feb 23 12:22 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apacheds apacheds 15346 Feb 23 12:22 apacheds
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apacheds apacheds 99401 Feb 23 12:22 wrapper

Here is the entry for the passwd file
apacheds:x:1000:1000::/opt/apacheds-2.0.0-M10:/bin/sh
so I don't think it is a id issue.

I am running Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-38-generic x86_64)

Has anyone ever seen anything like this? I have search google, but nothing has come up.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing absolutely same behaviour. As of now I am using java (.tar not .deb or .bin) version without the wrapper. I can be started by bin/apacheds.sh script. It is not the best solution but it let me going.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to run a 64bit executable on a 32bit configuration...